# HardDisk Space 500 GB but displays as 311.9 GB

Tags: 15.04

This is my 1st-time experience with Ubuntu which was installed by a friend on my computer. When I clicked on "About this computer", it displayed my 500 GB Disk as q 311.9 GB Disk:
[image: Screenshot]
So my questions are:

1. where is my remaining 188.1 GB
2. Please answer with screen-shots to help me get the remaining Disk Space. **as i am a 1st time user of this OS**

Comment: Please, open the dash (top left button in left panel) and search for Disks (or "disks" in your language") and edit your question with screenshot of your hardrive in this app.

Comment: Try opening the terminal and typing `df -m` (see the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html) for df).  This command reports disk usage for all of your partitions and disks.  The first column is the device (or partition) name, though you should ignore anything that doesn't start with `/dev` for now.  The second column is the total number of megabytes in that partition.  This is what you're interested in.  See if you can't find the extra 180 or so GB. A screenshot of the command output couldn't hurt, either.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please press [Ctrl][Alt][T] and then type `df --all --human`, then [edit] your question and provide the output of that command into your question!  Then leave a comment @Fabby.

Comment: While not directly related, you do know Vivid Vervet (15.04) reached End of Life on February 4, 2016.  Post this also: `sudo lshw -C Disk -short` What does BIOS/UEFI show for drive?